# How can I use the space above the navigation bar on Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, xamarin.android

I have the following problem: in all activities of an Android app there is a blank (black) space above the navigation bar at the bottom, on specific devices (Pixel 3a and Redmi Note 8T):

[image: Gap above navigation bar, as if the navigation bar extends above.]

I have tried many things, most search results have to do with setting the app to full screen, which basically only takes care of the status bar (either hiding it or making it translucent). The devices I have tested this with are on Android 9.0 and 10.0.

Now, it is important to note that on the Redmi Note 8T (Android 9.0) there is this button in the navigation bar:

[image: Tapping the button on the right]

If I tap this button, app needs to be started again, but the gap is gone (correct):

[image: No gap, correct!]

How can I get rid of this gap programmatically?

Comment: I think this may be caused by the customization of different mobile phone manufacturers

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT Thank you for your comment. I don't think it has to do with different manufacturers, as when I create a new project, activities appear correctly.

Comment: Since I could not reproduce your situation, though I tested it on pixel 3, it's just a guess,maybe i miss something.

Comment: Hi, I have a similar problem. Did you manage to find out the root cause?

Comment: @jack_the_beast. I just saw your comment. I am sorry, no solution found. Eventually that app is being re-written.

Comment: @DimitrisTavlikos I did find a solution eventually, posted it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll just post this here as it might help someone. I had a similar problem, the solution was to add

```
android:resizeableActivity="true"
```

to the `<application>` tag in the manifest.

hope this helps someone

Comment: Hey thanks! Still marking it as accepted answer for reference.